# Can't bind variable to wrapped open formula

Tags: coq

First, in the case of usual open formula,

```
Require Import Coq.Init.Nat.

Variable x : nat.

Lemma test1:
  ~ exists a : nat,
    let x := a in
    x * x = 2.
Proof.
  simpl. Admitted.
```

I can see that `a` binds to `x`, after `simpl.`.

```
1 subgoal
______________________________________(1/1)
~ (exists a : nat, a * a = 2)
```

Now, I write wrapped open formula `formula` based on `Prop`,
with an unwrap operation `f2p`.

```
Require Import Coq.Init.Nat.
Require Import Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.

(* I: injection, A: and, T: then, S: square *)
Inductive formula := I (p : Prop) | A (f g : formula) | T (p : Prop) (f : formula) | S (f : formula).

(* unwrap formula to prop *)
Fixpoint f2p (f : formula) : Prop :=
  match f with
  | I p => p
  | A f g => f2p(f) /\ f2p(g)
  | T p  f => p -> f2p(f)
  | _ => True
  end.

Definition andl (l : list Prop) : Prop :=
  fold_left and l True.

Variable x : nat.

Lemma test2:
  let l := [I (x*x = 2)] in
  ~ exists a : nat,
    let x := a in
    andl (map f2p l).
Proof.
  unfold andl. simpl.
  Admitted.
```

But in this case, I can NOT see that `a` binds to `x`, after `simpl.`.

```
1 subgoal
______________________________________(1/1)
~ (exists _ : nat, True /\ x * x = 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot see it because it is not what happens.
You have expression

```
let x := a in andl (map f2p l)
```

which does define `x` to be `a` in `andl (map f2p l)` but this term does not mention `x` as you can see. It does mention another variable called `x`:

```
Variable x : nat.
```

but they are not the same!

When you write `let x := a in exp` you have a *local* definition `x := a` in the context of expression `exp` so you can write `let x := a in x * x` and it will reduce to `a * a`.
What you are trying to do is not do a local definition but instantiating a variable, the way this is done is by using function application.

```
let l := fun x => [I (x*x = 2)] in
  ~ exists a : nat,
    let x := a in
    andl (map f2p (l x)).
```